# How to find if there's arithmatic mean of contiguous elements in a sorted array that equals to a given value in the most efficient running time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-efficiency

**INPUT:**

- Sorted array of positive, natural numbers,

**EXPECTED COMPLEXITY:**

- Time: `O(n)`
- Additional space: `O(1)`

**Example:**

**Input:**

`arr = {2,3,17,30}`
`x=10`

**Expected behavior:**

The function prints the indexes : 1,2 and returns true since (3+17)/2 = x = 10

**Input:**

`x = 30`

**Expected behavior:**

The function will print the index 3
and return true since `(30)/1` = x = 30`

My approach to the algorithm:

we will take the arithmatic mean starting with the first element in the array. If x is greater than our result we will add the next element in the array to the arithmatic mean.Else we will subtract the first element from the arithmatc  mean.

I tried it and it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does `O(n)` complexity in your Q means? You want the algorithm to be linear or you already have a linear one?

Comment: It means he was asked about it on an interview :)

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak I want the algorithm to be linear. and without using any  auxiliary space

Comment: @Dam you have a working procedure below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the largest k, for which sum of a0+a1+a2+...+ak <= k*target
2. If sum == k*target - ok
3. If sum != k*target - add next element, and then subtract first elements until the average becomes smaller or equal than the target.

If your k reaches array length, no solution. Else you have the solution. Complexity O(n) as if step 3 you only add one number as previous sum + ak+1 was greater than k*target and you can only move left border only n times.

```
1. proc(array, x):
2.     sum = 0;
3.     left = 0;
4.     right = 0;
5.     do:
6.         sum += array[right];
7.         right++;
8.     while (sum+array[right] <= (right+1)*target && right<array.size);
9.     if (sum == right*target):
10.        for (i = left; i < right; i++):
11.            print(array[i] + <sep>);
12.        end_for
13.        return;
14.    end_if
15.    while (left <= right):
16.        if (right<array.size): sum += array[right++];
17.        do:
18.            sum-=array[left++]
19.        while (sum > target*(right-left));
20.        if (sum == target*(right-left)):
21.            for (i = left; i < right; i++):
22.                print(array[i] + <sep>);
23.            end_for
24.            return;
25.        end_if
26.    end_while
27.end_proc
```

Working properly for arrays with all numbers positive. Small modifications required for negatives but on interviews they often ask about arrays with all numbers positive. Some additional escape conditions might be needed in case there is no proper solution.

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful.

Comment: @Dam You're welcome. It was a very interesting problem to solve! If you could remove your upvote and make it tommorow - I would award a golden badge. Don't remove the accept sign :)

Comment: . Yea . I had it in my test yesterday for the course "introduction to computer science". :)

Comment: This can't work. We always increase the average hoping it to become small enough.

Comment: @xenteros Thanks for tip. I implemented your solution and tested, and I am wondering what I am missing. Let's try an example
given {1,4,6,7,17,19,20} x = 5,
We find k = 3, and sum  = 18
after adding next element sum = 35
try obtain smaller average:
sum = 34, average = 8.5
sum = 30, average = 10
sum = 24, average = 12
sum = 17, average = 17
What's next? we've missed elements {4, 6}

Answer (score 0):

If we calculated the average of `k` elements `from 0 to k`, what we can tell about average `from 1 to k`, or about `from 0 to k + 1`?
Both averages `1 to k` and `0 to k + 1` are equal or greater to the average of first `k` elemnts.
Why?
Going from subset `from 0 to k` to subset `from 1 to k`, means removing the least element, so may not decrease total average.
Going from subset `from 0 to k` to subset `from 0 to k + 1`, means adding an element which isn't smaller that every other, so it may not decrease total average.

Do we know which number from given array must be part of the result? Yes, this is the last smaller or equal to the target. Why?
When it is equal, then we are done
When it is not equal, then we need to have both bigger and lower elements.

Then, we maintain the average increasing it by adding elements from right side, and decreasing from left side.

```
public static int[] findMean(int[] input, int target) {
    int firstGreater = 0;
    int n = input.length;
    while(firstGreater < n && input[firstGreater] <= target) firstGreater++; // use binary search instead!
    if(firstGreater == 0 || firstGreater == n) return new int[]{-1,-1};
    int left = firstGreater - 1, right = firstGreater;
    long sum = input[left];
    while ((right < n &&(right - left) * target > sum) || (left > 0 && (right - left) * target < sum)) {
        if((right - left) * target > sum) sum += input[right++];
        else sum += input[--left];
    }
    if((right - left) * target != sum) {
        left = right = -1;
    }
    return new int[]{left, right - 1};
}
```